# Objective-c: simple strings (beginner)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Can't seem to get this code working:

```
-(IBAction)enter:(id)sender {
    word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", display1, display2, display3, display4, display5, display6, display7, display8, display9];

    {
        display.text = word;
    }
```

It seems pretty basic, but every time I hit the `'enter'` button, the app stops running.
Each of the displays are labels and THEY ARE ALL SINGLE CHARACTERS.

My aim is to have the program output the word that characters spell.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use display1.text, display2.text etc. in stringWithFormat method

Comment: Does labels mean objects of UILabele class?

Comment: Stop running? What error it shows?

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran Already gave that a go and it didn't work

Comment: 9 variables!!! use arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the displays are `UILabel` objects, then change this 
 `word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", display1, display2, display3, display4, display5, display6, display7, display8, display9];` 
 to
 `word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", display1.text, display2.text, display3.text, display4.text, display5.text, display6.text, display7.text, display8.text, display9.text];`

Answer (score 0):

If display1 is declared as

```
char display1;
```

I must use specifier %c to print it

```
word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c", display1, display2, display3, display4, display5, display6, display7, display8, display9];
```